# Python child process keyboard input spoofing

Tags: input, keyboard, pipe, child-process, spoofing

Several commands on linux require a keyboard input to complete the process, in particular when a password is requested, or a yes/no confirmation.

I have no problems issuing the command in python and getting the results, but how do I automatically answer/spoof the proper answer to a child prompt and get the return code from `os.system` ?

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using the [pexpect](http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) library, which does exactly what you're asking for.

```
import pexpect
>>> child = pexpect.spawn('ssh user@myhost')
>>> child.expect('password:')
>>> child.sendline('123password')
>>> child.expect('Welcome to myhost, user')
>>> print 'successfully authenticated'
```